# Using Get-ChildItem but only look at the 2nd level down

Tags: script, powershell

This is probably really simple but I can't seem to find the answer. I'm looking for a way to only look in the second level down of a folder for a file.

i.e.

C:\Data

C:\Data\Level1

C:\Data\Level1\Level2\

I only want to look in the 2nd level, i.e. C:\Data\Level1\Level2\ in the example above.

What am I missing?

Currently, I'm using this script and I want to modify it to only look in the 2nd level down and ignore the first level.

```
Get-ChildItem '\\nas2\files\-- TV --\*\*' | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'folder.jpg'} | ForEach-Object {
$CurrentFolder = $_.Directory
if ((Test-Path "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg") -eq $false)
{Copy-Item $_ "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg"}
Remove-Variable CurrentFolder}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will check for the second level of the folder for both \Nas1\folder1\folder2 and c:\folder1\folder2 cases. Basically each \\\S* in the regex is a level.

Edit: added an additional check to ensure the level 2 folder contains a file named folder.jpg.

```
Get-ChildItem 'c:\temp' -recurse | `
Where-Object {($_.directoryname -match '^\\\\\S*\\\S*\\\S*$' -or $_.directoryname -match '^\S*\\\S*\\\S*\\\S*$') -and $_.Name -eq 'folder.jpg'} `
| ForEach-Object {
$CurrentFolder = $_.Directory
if ((Test-Path "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg") -eq $false)
{Copy-Item $_ "$CurrentFolder\show.jpg"}
Remove-Variable CurrentFolder}
```

In case you have folder names containing spaces, use this regex instead:

```
^\\\\.*\\.*\\.*$
```

and

```
^.*\\.*\\.*\\.*$
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Am I missing something in here? I don't see where it looks for folder.jpg. Maybe it's just me trying to multi-task right now. I'll check it out in a bit.

Comment: Indeed, it's not, I overlooked that part while focusing on the second level problem. I will add it asap.